# IllegalArgumentException. No view found for id: while capturing images in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera, illegalargumentexception

I am using the native camera app in a fragment in my app. But it throws IllealArgumentException  error randomly. Sometimes it works perfectly sometimes it doesn't.

What happens is after capturing image when I save the image the app crashes throwing the error. I think this is because I am using nested fragments in my app.

My activity launches a "HomeFragment" first up in a framelayout. This "HomeFragment" also has a framelayout inside it, where its child fragments are launched.

The fragment where I am capturing images is also one of these child fragments.

This is my capturing code -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And this is what I do in onActivityResult method, which by the way I've overridden in fragment itself.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

                previewCapturedImage();

            } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Image capturing cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }


    }
```

Here is the logcat data -

```
05-30 11:39:31.885  12798-12798/com.cgt.myHAE W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting          with uncaught exception (group=0x4128f930)
05-30 11:39:34.908  12798-12798/com.cgt.myHAE E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.cgt.myHAE/com.cgt.myHAE.MyHAE_HomeActivity}:      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09007e (com.cgt.myHAE:id/myAttackFrame) for fragment myAttackListFrag{41e73ea8 #5 id=0x7f09007e}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3783)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09007e (com.cgt.myHAE:id/myAttackFrame) for fragment myAttackListFrag{41e73ea8 #5 id=0x7f09007e}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5293)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3783)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 11:39:36.149  12798-12802/com.cgt.myHAE D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 3349K, 13%    free 24012K/27588K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 27ms
```

Comment: Post your relevant code and logcate.

Comment: i edited with logcat, please see this.

Comment: the code you posted has nothing to do with the logcat you posted, you need to provide us with the oncreate method of the activity you are trying to load. Possible problems :1. you are loading wrong xml, 2. your xml does not have the given view

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I have the same issue.